# "[(ngModel)]" not binding in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm building an Ionic application, currently migrating from Ionic 3 to 4. I've got some code which works perfectly in Ionic 3, but not in 4.
Basically, I can't seem to bind data with [(ngModel)] in an input field. I've imported `FormsModule` and added it among my imports in my `app.module.ts`. Here's how my `-component.ts` file looks like:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  someString: string = "test";
  ...
}
```

And my `-component.html`

```
<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="someString"></ion-input>
{{someString}}
```

Now in my application, `{{someString}}` rightly shows "test". However, changing the value of the input doesn't affect the `someString` variable in any way. What could I be missing?

Comment: can u share stackblitz link of your code ? i have tried the same thing on stack blitz and it is working perfectly when i change the value of input it correctly reflects. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-sxnxcs for your reference

Comment: @RahulLad of course it'll work. You're using Ionic 3, XD

Comment: ngmodel is discontinued  in latest ionic versions, and now it supports angular reactive forms

Comment: Call a method that changes the value of the variable. like forcing it to refresh.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Note: This is a workaround, not the solution. See my edit below**

Curiously, the [Ionic 4 input documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input) has no mention of `ngModel`, and rather talks of a `value` attribute. So I figured, I'd replace `[(ngModel)]` with `[value]`.

```
<ion-input type="text" [value]="someString"></ion-input>
```

To be able to access that value in my `-component.ts` file, I do something like:

**-component.html**

```
<ion-input type="text" [value]="someString" (input)="do_something($event)"></ion-input>
```

**-component.ts**

```
do_something($event) {
  this.someString = $event.target.value;
}
```

**EDIT**

Before using the above solution, be certain you're using `[(ngModel)]` and not `[ngModel]`. Contrary to what my question stated, `[(ngModel)]` actually works. I was rather using `[ngModel]`

Answer (score 1):

I was just struggling with the same issue but found solution why [(ngModel)] was not working in Ionic 4 for me.

First of all, you need to have CommonModule imported in your app.module. One more thing is to add your component into app.module declarations.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent,
                YourComponents],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule,
            CommonModule,
            FormsModule,
            IonicModule.forRoot(),
            AppRoutingModule
          ],
  providers: [SystemSettingsProviderService,
             { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

From now on, ngModel, ngIfs/Fors are working just fine.